# Changing colour of Tkintermapview Polygon during run

Tags: python, tkinter, tkintermapview

I am creating a program that requires changing the colour of a polygon using tkintermapview during the program. I have tried the following:

```
polygon1 = map_widget.set_polygon([(52, -1),
                                   (52.5, -1.1),
                                   (52.2, -1.5)],
                                  fill_color = 'red',
                                  name='Test location')

polygon1.fill_color = 'black'
print(polygon1.fill_color)
```

output:

```
'black'
```

However, the colour on the map does not change from red to black. How would I achieve the desired outcome?

Comment: Changing the attribute `fill_color` does not update the *polygon* item already drew on the map.  There is no function provided by `map_widget` to update the *polygon*.  You need to study the source code and find the way to update the *polygon* manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the attribute `fill_color` will not update the *polygon* already drawn on the map automatically.

As the map is drawn in a tkinter `Canvas` object and the polygon is a polygon item of the canvas object, so you can using `Canvas.itemconfig()` to change the fill color you want as below:

```py
polygon1 = map_widget.set_polygon([(52, -1),
                                   (52.5, -1.1),
                                   (52.2, -1.5)],
                                  fill_color = 'red',
                                  name='Test location')

map_widget.canvas.itemconfig(polygon1.canvas_polygon, fill="yellow")
```

Note that `map_widget.canvas` is the `Canvas` object and `polygon1.canvas_polygon` is the item ID of the polygon item (according to the source code of `tkintermapview`).

Result:

[image]